# Connect klip xtreme bluetooth headset to ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, 15.04

I am trying to connect an klip xtreme khs-630 bluetooth headset to an Ubuntu 15.04 dual boot laptop.

I am able to connect it, and in sound settings I see it under "play through", but when I select it, settings displayed is still for speakers not for the headset.

[image]

I have tried the pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover but i get the Failure: Module initialization failed error.

Comment: Is it actually playing sound through the speakers instead of the headset?

Comment: no it is not only through the speakers

Comment: Not only? So it's playing on both the headset and the speakers?

Comment: no it not playing on headset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer!

I just had to open Ubuntu Software center and search for pavu
then install PulseAudio Volume Contorl (first in the list)
and finally go to configuration tab and set the headset profile on A2DP

[image]